# strncat looks like its preserving data across calls?

Tags: c, strcat

I am seeing some odd behavior out of the `strncat` function in the `string.h` standard library, and would like some help understanding what is going on.

---

The crux of my issue is in a function I created called `readLine` with the purpose of returning the lines of a file as `char *` strings without a trailing newline terminator. That function looks like this:

```
char * readLine(FILE * fp) {
    char * chunk = NULL;
    char * line = NULL;
    int count = 0;

    // iterate through chunks of a line until we reach the end (or an error)
    while (fgets((chunk = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE)), BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {

        // realloc on a null pointer works like malloc  
        line = realloc(line, ++count * BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));    

        printf("chunk's contents: %s\n", chunk);

        // does chunk contain the end of a line?
        if(strchr(chunk, '\n') == NULL) {   
            // concatenate string parts and continue loop
            strncat(line, chunk, strlen(chunk) + 1);        
            free(chunk);

        } else {
            // we want to return a \0 terminated string without the \n
            // expected position of \n in chunk is ({length of chunk}-1)
            chunk[(strlen(chunk) - 1)] = '\0';

            // concatenate string parts
            strncat(line, chunk, strlen(chunk) + 1);
            printf("readLine line:    %s\n", line);
            free(chunk);

            break;        
        }        
    }
    return line;
}
```

I call it in main in a loop that looks like this:

```
FILE * fp = NULL;

if ((fp = fopen(FILE_PATH, "r")) != NULL) {
    char * line = NULL;

    while ((line = readLine(fp)) != NULL) {
        printf("main line:        %s\n\n", line);
        free(line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

---

Now the odd behavior comes in my definition of `#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000`. With it set like that I get the following output (which is not what I want):

```
chunk's contents: I am on line 1
readLine line:    I am on line 1
main line:        I am on line 1

chunk's contents: Over here I am on line 2
readLine line:    I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2
main line:        I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2

chunk's contents: Line 3 here
readLine line:    I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2Line 3 here
main line:        I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2Line 3 here

chunk's contents: Look out for 4
readLine line:    I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2Line 3 hereLook out for 4
main line:        I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2Line 3 hereLook out for 4

chunk's contents: Johnny 5 alive!
readLine line:    I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2Line 3 hereLook out for 4Johnny 5 alive!
main line:        I am on line 1Over here I am on line 2Line 3 hereLook out for 4Johnny 5 alive!
```

---

**BUT** if i change that definition to something like `#define BUFFER_SIZE 20`, I get the output I am looking for:

```
chunk's contents: I am on line 1

readLine line:    I am on line 1
main line:        I am on line 1

chunk's contents: Over here I am on l
chunk's contents: ine 2

readLine line:    Over here I am on line 2
main line:        Over here I am on line 2

chunk's contents: Line 3 here

readLine line:    Line 3 here
main line:        Line 3 here

chunk's contents: Look out for 4

readLine line:    Look out for 4
main line:        Look out for 4

chunk's contents: Johnny 5 alive!

readLine line:    Johnny 5 alive!
main line:        Johnny 5 alive!
```

---

I think I have the problem narrowed down to the `strncat(line, chunk, strlen(chunk) + 1);` line. I don't understand why the preceding `line`s are being included when my `BUFFER_SIZE` is sufficiently high.

Comment: Try to memset your buffers to 0 before using them.

Comment: Note that your `strncat` is implementing Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: Notice that with `line = realloc(line, ...` you will have an unrecoverable memory leak should realloc fail and return NULL (which you should check for). The `realloc` function is horrible from an API point of view, among other reasons because it invites to write incorrect code like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
line = realloc(line, ++count * BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

does not initialise the allocated memory. So if the first `realloc` in `readLine` gives you back the chunk of memory you got in the previous invocation - not impossible, you may have the old contents still in there.

Anyway, with uninitialised memory, the first `strncat` may invoke undefined behaviour, since there need not be a 0 byte in the allocated memory.

Allocate a buffer to `line` before entering the loop, and write a `0` to the first byte.

Also, don't use

```
line = realloc(line, ++count * BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

If `realloc` fails, you leak memory. And you should check the return value of `realloc`,

```
char *temp = realloc(line, ++count * BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
if (temp == NULL) {
  // Oops
} else {
    line = temp;
}
```

And don't `malloc` to `chunk` in the `fgets` call,

```
while (fgets((chunk = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE)), BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
```

If `malloc` fails, that invokes undefined behaviour too. `malloc` and check before calling `fgets`,

```
while ((chunk = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE)) && fgets(chunk, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
```

Comment: great answer, Thank You. 

In the `realloc` idiom, would it be appropriate to `free(line)` if `temp == NULL`? 

I really like that while condition revision too

Comment: Yes, then `line` still points to allocated memory that shall be `free`d. What sort of diagnostic and recovery/cleanup before exit you do when `realloc` fails depends.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick with `realloc` and memset your buffers to zero before, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
    line = realloc(line, ++count * BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

According to the man page for `realloc`:

```
"realloc(3) does not guarantee that the additional memory is also
 zero-filled."
```

and

```
"If ptr is NULL, realloc() is identical to a call to malloc() for size bytes."
```

So any new memory you get is likely to be filled with non-zero bytes, meaning the first time it is called, it's probably not going to have a 0 for the first byte, which means that strncat  is going to be appending to whatever junk bytes are in the allocation.